# How to remove "mandatory" for a particular field in WordPress comment form

Tags: html, wordpress, validation

I've launched my first website in WordPress using bootstrap theme. My site is [www.youthenext.com](http://www.youthenext.com)

Even though I've not set mandatory for wesite field, form is not submiting without filling the form field. You can [see the form here](http://youthenext.com/tips-to-prepare-your-first-and-best-resume-2/)

I don't know which file I have to edit.

Comment: Is the form being built with a plugin?  If so, which plugin?  Or did you manually build it?

Comment: Its not a plugin and all...
I have just installed Wordpress Bootstrap theme...
The insert field is also default one...
You can also try the same bug at [this link http://320press.com/wpbs/v2-1-released/](http://320press.com/wpbs/v2-1-released/)